# JS Error for Angular and Nativescript project

Tags: angularjs, npm, nativescript, tns, angular-hybrid

Current behavior
When I try to run the application using tns run ios , it gives me the following error.
[attached picture shows the JS Error in  the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Zwx.png)

Expected behavior
The app should boot up without the JS error just like the web application.

Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

git clone "name of the repository"
npm i
cd nativescript
npm i
tns run ios
It installs the app successfully , however, the app doesn't open. On manually opening the app, it gives a JS error.

What is the motivation / use case for changing the behavior?

To get the web and mobile running at the same time.

Please tell us about your environment:

Operating system : MAC OS (Tried it on windows too) 16GB RAM
package manager : npm, tns

**Angular Seed Version: 8aae926
Node: node --version = v8.11.3

Comment: Post the JS error if you need people to help you determine what is wrong

Comment: The error can be found in the original post where it says "attached picture shows the JS Error in the terminal"

Comment: Your files are typescript. How are you compiling your project? 
https://www.nativescript.org/using-typescript-with-nativescript-when-developing-mobile-apps

Comment: We are using tns run ios/android for mobile and ng serve --o for web